# How to make maven javadoc:javadoc fail at end on multi module project?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, multi-module

I am doing a strict javadoc validation on a multi module maven project using `mvn javadoc:javadoc -Dmaven.javadoc.failOnWarnings="true" --fail-at-end` on the project aggregator.

I would expect each project's javadoc to be analyzed and be able to see all errors and warnings at the end of the build. However, the build fails on the first module with warnings or errors (as expected) and marks the next modules as banned and skip them (not expecting that with `--fail-at-end`).

```
mvn javadoc:javadoc -Dmaven.javadoc.failOnWarnings="true" -fae

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] project-A                                                          [pom]
[INFO] project-B                                                          [jar]
[INFO] project-C                                                          [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project-A                                                [1/3]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:javadoc (default-cli) > generate-sources @ project-A >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:javadoc (default-cli) < generate-sources @ project-A <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:javadoc (default-cli) @ project-A ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project-B                                                [2/3]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:javadoc (default-cli) > generate-sources @ project-B >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:javadoc (default-cli) < generate-sources @ project-B <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:javadoc (default-cli) @ project-B ---
[INFO]
Loading source files for package ...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 13.0.1
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating ...
Building index for all the packages and classes...
Generating ...
Building index for all classes...
Generating ...
1 warning
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] MyClass.java:48: warning: no @return
[WARNING] public static String myMethod() {
[WARNING] ^
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping project-C
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] project-A ..................................................... SUCCESS [  1.888 s]
[INFO] project-B ..................................................... FAILURE [  2.993 s]
[INFO] project-C ..................................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I have to fix warnings/errors on project-B, then relaunch the command to see if there are warnings/errors on project-C.

Is there a way to get the javadoc analysis result of all warnings/errors in all projects at once ?

Comment: What about `-Dmaven.javadoc.failOnWarnings=false`?

Comment: @khmarbaise the same behavior happens with only errors, the modules after the first error are skipped. I want a strict validation so I want the overall project build status marked as failed when there are warnings on a module. What I would like to achieve is: analyze each modules and get the final report of warnings/errors on all modules without having to fix each module and relaunch the command every time there's an error/warning.